# Check if caps lock on in terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

Is there a way to query the system to tell if the caps lock is on or is off from the command line in terminal.app?

Comment: Wouldn't typing one letter show you immediately the status of the caps lock? What's the actual use of this information. Perhaps you're asking about [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? There are third-party utilities that can tell you the state of the modifier keys however nothing native (installed by default) that I know of, but that doesn't mean there isn't.

Comment: I am using the LED to indicate that the input source is Greek. I want it to be off only if input source is English and caps lock is off.

Comment: @Lawrence Now that's a cool setup. If you wanted to add that to the question - awesome. I bet lots of people would love to know how you accomplished that modification.

Comment: I used Karabiner and busyloop/maclight from Github.

Comment: Please add your two last interesting comments within your original question. This will save you time and answers out of spot.

Comment: Better remap Caps Lock altogether to something else, e.g. `Control`. It usually creates much confusion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a great command line code written by [Stefenk on Macscripter](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?pid=114479#p114479)

Stefen's code allows you to detect for cmd, option, control, shift, and caps lock.

In his post he provides the code and a download zip of it.

You can either download it or build your own in Xcode using foundation project.

I just tested both ways in El Capitan and they both work.

The code if you want to build your own in Xcode.app is:

```
#import <Carbon/Carbon.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        unsigned int modifiers = GetCurrentKeyModifiers();
        if (argc == 1)
            printf("%d\n", modifiers);
        else {
            int i, result = 1;
            for (i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
                if (0 == strcmp(argv[i], "shift"))
                    result = result && (modifiers & shiftKey);
                else if (0 == strcmp(argv[i], "option"))
                    result = result && (modifiers & optionKey);
                else if (0 == strcmp(argv[i], "cmd"))
                    result = result && (modifiers & cmdKey);
                else if (0 == strcmp(argv[i], "control"))
                    result = result && (modifiers & controlKey);
                else if (0 == strcmp(argv[i], "capslock"))
                    result = result && (modifiers & alphaLock);
            }
            printf("%d\n", result);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

----------( update ->

If you want to compile it from Terminal.app

Put the code into a plain text file. I just used TextEdit.app and a Plain text document.

cd to the same directory as your file.  Make sure that the extension is .m ( .c will be ok also)

Then Run.

```
gcc  -framework Carbon CheckModKeys.m -o CheckModKeys
```

CheckModKeys.m is your file.

CheckModKeys  is the name of the app to be outputted.

<-)

---

To detect caps lock your command would look something like:

```
/Users/UserName/MyFolder/CheckModKeys  capslock
```

a 1 or 0 will be returned.

1 for on

0 for off

---

All credit goes to Stefen. I just remembered he posted this way back in`2009. And it still works today..

Comment: Thanks! How do I compile this? I tried `gcc -o getmod getmod.c` but that returned 
`getmod.c:4:5: error: expected expression
    @autoreleasepool {
    ^
1 error generated. `

Comment: @Lawrence  see updated answer

Comment: I still get:
``
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_objc_autoreleasePoolPop", referenced from:
      _main in main-93f6a5.o
  "_objc_autoreleasePoolPush", referenced from:
      _main in main-93f6a5.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
``

Comment: what OS are you doing this on

Comment: El Capitan. Just installed XCode for the purpose (though there was some version of gcc præsent from before).

Comment: What do you get if you enter `gcc --version` in terminal.

Comment: Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0
Thread model: posix

Comment: Thats look right so it is def. picking up the right gcc. Are able to take this to a chat. and show me the code you are using.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30336/discussion-between-lawrence-and-markhunte).

Comment: The chat is gone, and I can't compile it either. Where you able to compile it, @Toothrot ?

Comment: The chat is just set to read only. But they ended up using the link above to get the code which worked for them. Try that

Answer (score 2):

If you have [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/wiki) installed and either running or don't mind it launching, you can run: `xset -q`

```
Keyboard Control:
  auto repeat:  on    key click percent:  0    LED mask:  00000000
  XKB indicators:
    00: Caps Lock:   off    01: Num Lock:    off    02: Shift Lock:  off
    03: Group 2:     off    04: Mouse Keys:  off    05: Scroll Lock: off
```

Comment: I don't have `xset` on El Capitan using a default user account in bash. Is this part of a specific shell or something you have to install to have the command work?

Comment: @bmike, `xset` is part of `X11` which is not installed by default.  You can get it here: [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/wiki)

Comment: @Mikey T.K., The problem IMO with using `xset` is it causes XQuartz.app to open for it (`xset) to run in a Terminal.  To me this is undesired behavior as I'd just want a CLI utility that runs like any other BSD command.